# Using jQuery to add an image tag - How do I include a class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to add an img tag via the following jQuery:

```
var parentElement = $("#sidebar");

    var img1 = $('<img />', { 
        id: 'headerImageLeft',
        src: '/Images/Header/FGM.jpg',
        class: 'img-responsive',
        style: 'float: left;',
        width: 80,
        alt: ''
    });
    img1.appendTo(parentElement);
```

While this seems to work correctly, I'm not certain this is the proper way to add a class. In Visual Studio 2013, I'm getting a design time warning saying I'm using a future reserved word, Is this the correct way to add a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [jQuery docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/), because `class` is a [reserved word](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords), it needs to be quoted.

> Property names generally do not need to be quoted unless
>   they are [reserved words](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords) (as `class` is in this case).

So:

```
var img1 = $('<img />', { 
    id: 'headerImageLeft',
    src: '/Images/Header/FGM.jpg',
    "class": 'img-responsive',
    style: 'float: left;',
    width: 80,
    alt: ''
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `class` is an object key, it shouldn't matter that its a reserved word.  You could place it within quotes to remove the Visual Studio's warning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `class` *was* a reserved word in previous versions of ECMAScript standard but you could/can use the word as an IdentifierName (vs Identifiers, e.g. a variable), i.e. using "class" without quotes as a property name will work in all browsers that support version 5 of the ECMAScript. If supporting stone-aged browsers (e.g. IE8) matters you can wrap the property name with quotes otherwise you can ignore the warning.